# Any Good Patterns For Distributed Parallelism?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, plinq

I've got a for loop I want to parallelize with something like PLINQ's Parallel.ForEach().

The key here is that the C++ library i'm calling to do the computation is decidedly not thread safe, therefore, any plans to parallelize this need to do so across multiple processes.

I was thinking about using WCF to create a "distributor" process to which the "client" and multiple "calculators" could both connect and add/remove items to/from a queue and then the "calculator" sends the results directly back to the client which could update the gui as it receives them. This architecture would allow me to bring as many "calculators" online as I have processors and as I see it even bring them up across multiple computers creating a potential farm of processing power to which all the clients could share.

I'm just wondering if anyone has had any experience doing this and if there are existing application blocks or frameworks that I can use to build this for me. PLINQ does it within the process. is there like a DPLINQ (distributed) or something?

Also if that doesn't exist, does anybody want to give an opinion on my proposed architecture? Any obvious pitfalls? Does anyone think it will work!?!?!?

Comment: How large are the amounts of data you need to transfer between processes? From what I read WCF uses rather slow serializers. So if you transfer much data perhaps shared memory could be a good idea.

Comment: I would make sure the payoff is worth the investment of effort before you devote too much time to this. PLINQ is great because it gives you parallel processing for "free".

Comment: I get that PLINQ is great - but because of this issue of the libary being not thread safe I can't use it. The objects going out aren't that big, but the process creates some chunky data, maybe 40-50 arrays of 500 doubles each? I think the NetTCP serializer is fast enough to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you could be looking for [Dryad](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/DryadLINQ/). It's a Microsoft research project right now, but they do have an "academic release" available. My understanding is that they are also in the process of better productizing it (probably some kind of integration with Azure) for RTM sometime near the end of 2011. Mary Jo Foley covers more about this [here](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-research-parallel-programming-project-set-to-go-commercial-in-2011/7161).

Comment: Wow - this was exactly what I'm looking for. Looks like I got some reading to do.

Comment: Hmmm... Apparently both MPI and Dryad require HPC Server Licenses from Microsoft.

Comment: That is correct... for now anyway. Like I said you can bet you're going to see this become some kind of offering within the Azure PaaS at some point.

Comment: @skimania, MPICH is an MPI daemon implementation available for Windows: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/

Comment: dryad is [discontinued](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-drops-dryad-puts-its-big-data-bets-on-hadoop/11226)

Answer (score 2):

A long time standard for controlling/dispatching distributed work is [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface).  I've only ever used it from C++, but implementations from many languages exist.  A quick google suggests that [MPI.Net](http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/) could be a good implementation for .Net!

Comment: Actually, this MPI sounds much more mature as a platform than Dryad, but I really like the idea of an end-to-end MS solution, so I'm going to pursure that one first.